# tomcat 5.5 + nexus 1.9.2: Nexus doesn't start and Tomcat doesn't log anything

Tags: tomcat, debian, nexus

I installed Tomcat 5.5 (tomcat5.5) and the corrsponding admin package (tomcat5.5-admin) using APT on my Debian Lenny x64 server.
I configured the `tomcat-users.xml` and tomcat came up how I expected. Then I deployed the Nexus 1.9.2 webapp WAR-File using the tomcat-manager webapp.
The manager uploaded nexus to tomcat and extracted the files in the webapps directory.

When try to start nexus tomcat tells me on the admin webapp the following:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /nexus-webapp-1.9.2 could not be started
```

It read [here](http://www.idimmu.net/2009/03/20/Nexus-on-Tomcat-5.5-on-Ubuntu-Hardy) that I need to create the `sonatype-work/` directory under `/usr/share/tomcat5.5` and make it accessible to tomcat:

```
chown tomcat55 /usr/share/tomcat5.5/sonatype-work
```

I restarted tomcat `/etc/init.d/tomcat55 restart` but nothing changed. When I looked for the tomcat log files I found an empty directory under `/var/log/tomcat5.5`

Does anyone known what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check the nexus logs in sonatype work. It won't probably run because your tomcat is old. You will need at least 6 and Java 5 or even 6 to run it.

Comment: I looked into the sonatype-work directory but nexus doesn't create any files in it. I'm using JDK 6 so it would be probably the old version of tomcat. I saw that tomcat 6 is in the repo of Debian Squeeze. Is there a mirror providing tomcat6 for Lenny?

Comment: You can do a quick test by downloading Tomcat directly, unzip it and deploy Nexus. This should be proof enough. If this works, you can then run apt to update it.

Comment: Yeah. Under tomcat 6 it's running fine! thanks a lot.

Comment: I added the comment as an answer. Vote for please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the nexus logs in sonatype work. It won't probably run because your tomcat is old. You will need at least 6 and Java 5 or even 6 to run it.
You can do a quick test by downloading Tomcat directly, unzip it and deploy Nexus. This should be proof enough. If this works, you can then run apt to update it.